# Unable to Log certain lines

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

My `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` contains this part of code:

```
    val weatherService = RetrofitFactory.retrofit(AppConstants.OWM_API_URL)
        .create(OwmApi::class.java)
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val request = weatherService.getCurrentWeatherDataByName("Bengaluru", "metric")
        Log.i("Response 0", 0.toString())
        try {
            val response = request.await()
            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.i("Response 2", 2.toString())
                val weatherResponse = response.body()
                Log.i("Response 3", 3.toString())
                Log.i("Response", weatherResponse.toString())
                println(weatherResponse)
            }
            else {
                Log.i("Response 5", 5.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, response.errorBody().toString())
            }
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            e.stackTrace
        }
    }
```

The `weatherService`'s client contains an interceptor whose definition is as follows:

```
private val loggingInterceptor =  HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
}
```

Now when I run my app, **I only see the Log with tag of Response 0**, but not Response, or even the `else` part of my code when I change the query parameters to invalid values. Maybe this has something to do with the `loggingInterceptor` but I'm still not sure why certain Log messages don't appear despite the `response.isSuccessful` part being true.

Comment: do you get any exception? because you called api in main thread`(Dispatchers.Main)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your api call in background thread may be it's getting exception.

so try like below

```
 val weatherService = RetrofitFactory.retrofit(AppConstants.OWM_API_URL)
    .create(OwmApi::class.java)
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val request = weatherService.getCurrentWeatherDataByName("Bengaluru", "metric")
    Log.i("Response 0", 0.toString())
    try {
        val response = request.await()
        if(response.isSuccessful) {
            Log.i("Response 2", 2.toString())
            val weatherResponse = response.body()
            Log.i("Response 3", 3.toString())
            Log.i("Response", weatherResponse.toString())
            println(weatherResponse)
        }
        else {
            Log.i("Response 5", 5.toString())
            Log.d(TAG, response.errorBody().toString())
        }
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        e.stackTrace
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "No filter" option on

Comment: Can you include code or screenshots in your answer to improve its quality?

Comment: Please add some code how to set that opeion and explain, why this works!

Comment: Where should i set this option? Could you please give a code example so that i can understand better..